# Out of memory exception trying to write large amount of data to a file

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write a large amount of unsorted data (50000000 numbers) to a file. At runtime I get an `OutOfMemoryException`. How to fix it?

```
private void backgroundWorkerGenNum_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int numLimit = 50000000;
    Random randomize = new Random();
    List<string> strNums = new List<string>();

    var array = Enumerable.Range(1, numLimit).ToArray();
    array = array.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("numbers.txt");
    int i = 0;
    foreach(int element in array)
    {
        file.WriteLine(element);
        ++i;
        backgroundWorkerGenNum.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your error's full stack trace, please.

Comment: Post ReportProgress as well

Comment: Also: `StreamWriter` implements `IDisposable` and therefore its lifetime should be wrapped in a `using` construct so it is deterministically disposed.

Comment: @Logan Then the numbers couldn't be randomly distributed throughout the entire sequence.

Comment: Your reporting of progress every iteration of the loop is going to slow down your program a lot. I recommend only reporting every 0.1 percent. First, figure out how often you will report outside of the loop `int reportEvery = Math.Max(1, numLimit / 1000);`, then only report when the modulo returns 0 `if( i % reportEvery == 0) { backgroundWorkerGenNum.ReportProgress(i); }`

Comment: I would try to avoid arrays altogether and just work on enumerables which are created and then processed sequentially in order to avoid the need to hold them all in memory at the same time.

Comment: You are all speaking about Shuffle-algorythmes, but I wanted to see  solution without outOfMemoryException problem.

Comment: @pragmus the reason people are talking about Shuffle is because you *do* a shuffle (order by GUID) and that is likely the OutOfMemory issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can just shuffle your array like this:

```
public static class ArrayExtender
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this T[] a)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = a.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int j = rand.Next(0, i + 1);
            T tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

well, now we can generate randomized data:

```
    private void backgroundWorkerGenNum_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int numLimit = 50000000;

        var array = Enumerable.Range(1, numLimit).ToArray();
        array.Shuffle();
        int i = 0;
        using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("numbers.txt"))
           foreach (int element in array)
           {
               file.WriteLine(element);
               ++i;
               backgroundWorkerGenNum.ReportProgress(i);
           }
    }
```

Comment: If you are going to show a corrected version of the code you should fix the undisposed StreamWriter too.

Comment: I'd probably also move the random number generator out of the method itself (class level `static readonly` member) and then the method can go even more generic and fluent with a signature of `public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> a)`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain sorry, I picked TS's code without editing :( Done.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I wrote this code for arrays because arrays get specific optimizations from compiler. Sure, you can write an overload for this method, if you will :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very inefficient way of randomizing a collection of numbers:

```
array = array.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
```

Each new Guid you generate requires 16 byes + a few bytes of overhead to store.

You have 5*10^7 numbers that you're randomizing by abusing the OrderBy method.

The OrderBy internally will attempt to sort your collection using the keys you provide which requires it to allocate memory for the data and keys. Assuming the Order By stores the generated key along with each element this would require more than 1GB of space in memory.

Comment: Not only is it inefficient, it cannot be relied on to actually *work*, as GUIDs are only guaranteed to be *unique* and not *random*.

Comment: @DeeMac Well, it is what it asserts to be.  As an implementation detail, that is actually a lie, in that collisions are technically possible, albeit not possible in a practical sense.  You can rely on a GUID being unique though, as that is what it's build to be.

Comment: `OrderBy` computes all of the keys in advance; it does not call the selector multiple times for each item.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using shuffle method like this

```
private void Shuffle(int[] data)
{
    var random = new Random();

    int n = data.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int idx = random.Next(i, n);

        int x = data[i];
        data[i] = data[idx];
        data[idx] = x;
    } 
}
```

instead of `array.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray()`